# List all things in thing groups in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am fetching things in thing group, I have around 500 things in a single thing group.
When I using aws java sdk api I am getting only 25 things in result.

```
ListThingsInThingGroupRequest listThingsInThingGroupRequest = new ListThingsInThingGroupRequest();
listThingsInThingGroupRequest.withThingGroupName(groupName);
ListThingsInThingGroupResult listThingsInThingGroupResult =  
    awsIot.listThingsInThingGroup(listThingsInThingGroupRequest);
    
List<String> arl = listThingsInThingGroupResult.getThings();

System.out.println("Size of List"+arl.size());
```

Getting only 25 things in arraylist. Tell me how to get all the things in thing group.

Answer (score 0):

The request is paginated. Use the next token and a while loop like this:

```
String nextToken = null;
List<String> things = new ArrayList<>();
do {
   ListThingsInThingGroupRequest listThingsInThingGroupRequest = new ListThingsInThingGroupRequest();
   listThingsInThingGroupRequest.withThingGroupName(groupName).withNextToken(nextToken);
   ListThingsInThingGroupResult listThingsInThingGroupResult = awsIot.listThingsInThingGroup(listThingsInThingGroupRequest);
   things.addAll(listThingsInThingGroupResult.getThings());
   nextToken = listThingsInThingGroupResults.nextToken;
} while (nextToken != null)
```